# How to capture parameters under universal quantification (using Modules? Sections?)

Tags: coq

I am wondering how best to handle this sort of situation in Coq:

Suppose I need to define and prove a number of things about an arbitrary structure (for the purposes of this discussion, let's say a set with a binary relation).  Of course, I can always supply the set and relation as arguments for each such definition/proof:

```
Inductive star (X : Set) (R : X -> X -> Prop) := ...

Lemma star_trans (X : Set) (R : X -> X -> Prop) : ...
```

Naturally, this gets tiresome after a while.  What I would like to do is have `X` and `R` as parameters locally within some demarcated area of code like so:

```
Parameter X : Set.
Parameter R : X -> X -> Prop.

Inductive star := ...
Lemma star_trans : ...
```

in such a way that the definitions and theorems, when used outside this area of code, capture `X` and `R` under universal quantification in order to give them the proper type.  For instance, `Check star` should yield `star : forall X : Set, (X -> X -> Prop) -> X -> X -> Prop`.

I figured that this might be what modules are for, but I can't figure out how to use them for this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what the "Section mechanism" does: see https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual004.html#Section .

```
Section rel_star.

Variables (X : Set) (R : X -> X -> Prop).

Inductive star := ...
Lemma star_trans: ...

End rel_star.
```

Comment: Thank you, I had tried this but it seems that my problem was using `Parameter` instead of `Variable`.